# Why isn't this cast working?

Tags: c#, collections

This code works:

```
foreach(DataColumn column in table.Columns)
{
    // do whatever
}
```

But this code doesn't:

```
(IEnumerable<DataColumn>)(table.Columns)
```

The `.Columns` property returns a [DataColumnCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumncollection.aspx) which is an [InternalDataCollectionBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumncollection.aspx), which implements IEnumerable, so it should work.

The error I get is

> Cannot convert type 'System.Data.DataColumnCollection' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`DataColumnCollection` implements `IEnumerable`, and each returned row *is* a `DataColumn`, but it doesn't implement `IEnumerable<DataColumn>`. As it doesn't implement the interface, you can't cast to the interface. As the class is sealed, the compiler *knows* that the value can't possibly implement the interface, so you can't even cast to it at compile-time.

Use the LINQ `Cast` method insted:

```
table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
```

That's effectively an adapter method - each element in the column collection will be lazily cast to `DataColumn` as you fetch it from the result.

The reason the `foreach` compiles is that the compiler adds an explicit cast for you. For instance, this will *compile*:

```
foreach (string x in table.Columns)
{
}
```

... but it'll throw an exception at execution time.

Answer (score 3):

It's because DataColumnCollection implements `IEnumerable`, but not `IEnumerable<T>` .

`var columns = (IEnumerable)(table.Columns)`  should work

IEnumerable and IEnumerable aren't related in any way. (however `IEnumerable<DataColumn>` inherits from `IEnumerable<object>` which could be duck typed to IEnumerable using dynamic, but it doesn't really help you (even if it's a lot of fun) )

Comment: I think you meant "[...] but not IEnumerable<DataColumn> [...]".

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you are individually casing each time within the Columns collection, but in the second you are casting the entire collection at once.  It's really no different than:

```
// Cats implements IAnimal
Cats[] cats = new Cats[20]; 
...
IAnimal animal = cats[0];
```

versus

```
// this you cannot do
Cats[] cats = new Cats[20]; 
IAnimal[] animal = cats;
```

However, it is moot, as you can do this:

```
table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
```

And be done with it.  Notice that using the `Cast<>` is preferable to simply getting a generic IEnumerable as the strong typing is preserved.

Answer (score 0):

This is because DataColumnCollection only implements `IEnumerable`, so you cannot cast it to the generic version `IEnumerable<DataColumn>`. When using `foreach`, the compiler does the casting for you on each element by convention.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var columns = table.Columns as IEnumerable;
```